# Help With SQL Query

Tags: database

I have the following code:

```
$my_result = db_query("SELECT nid FROM content_field_taxo_listing WHERE field_taxo_listing_value = '%s'", $tid);

while ($my_row = db_fetch_array($my_result)) {
  $nodeids[] = $my_row['nid'];
}
```

What I want to do is to join (it might be a union, but I am not sure) the "content_field_taxo_listing" table with the "node" table, and order the "nids" field by title in the "node" table.

What is the Drupal way for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$my_result = db_query("
  SELECT {content_field_taxo_listing}.nid 
  FROM {content_field_taxo_listing} LEFT JOIN {node} ON content_field_taxo_listing.nid = node.nid
  WHERE content_field_taxo_listing.field_taxo_listing_value = '%s'
  ORDER BY {node}.title", $tid);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answer, but it still does not SORT BY title from the node table

Comment: Sorry I forgot :) SELECT node.title, content_field_taxo_listing.nid 
  FROM {content_field_taxo_listing} LEFT JOIN {node} ON content_field_taxo_listing.nid = node.nid
  WHERE content_field_taxo_listing.field_taxo_listing_value = '%s' ORDER BY node.title

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much, very helpful indeed  merry christmas :)

Comment: Merry Christmas :)

Comment: @nourcy You should write what you wrote in your comment in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$my_result = db_query("
  SELECT ctl.nid 
  FROM {content_field_taxo_listing} ctl 
  LEFT JOIN {node} n ON ctl.nid = n.nid
  WHERE ctl.field_taxo_listing_value = :tid 
  ORDER BY n.title ASC",
  array(":tid"=>$tid)
);
```

Comment: What does ctl do? Never seen that before. The code from nourcy works perfectly.

Comment: @user4560 - It's just an alias for the actual tablename. Have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: Tried reading the link, however my brain got fried! Do you really read stuff like this?

Comment: @user4560 - Haha, yes sometimes=)